# Converting Cisco CDR DateTime and Duration in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am creating a report in SSRS that pulls data including Call Date and Duration from a table with Cisco CDR data. Both fields store the data as a bigint datatype. I understand that the Date/Time field is Unix Epoch Time.

My challenge is that I need to display the date/time and duration correctly in the report but I am not sure how to create the appropriate expression in SSRS to accomplish this. I will also need to enable the user to run the report by entering Start and End Date parameters. I would greatly appreciate some assistance

Comment: Share your dataset in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Convert Function to get what you want when pulling it in.

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, <your date field>, 120)
```

120 is the date style you want. 120 specifically is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)
 All the styles are found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Parameters are easy either in your data set create a stored procedure and add them into the stored procedure. Then they will get created automatically. If you are using plain text query then in your query then:

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
```

Then be sure to use them in you where clause with a between statement:

```
WHERE CONVERT(Datetime, <your date field>, 120) 
BETWEEN CONVERT(Datetime, @StartTime, 120) AND CONVERT(Datetime, @EndDate, 120)
```

This way you can be sure to keep all your dates the same format so you get the correct results in your query.

If you are using plain text after this go to the parameters tab right click and create new parameter and then name it @BeginningDate and select DATE\TIME data type then do the same for the seocnd calling it @FinishingDate. After you create those right click on your Data set and go to properties and then go to the parameters tab and  under parameter name enter @StartDate and paramter value type [@BeginningDate] this means the value of @BeginningDate and then do the same for @EndDate and @FinishingDate then it should work. Date/time parameters create a date picker automatically in the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
DATEADD(s, epoch, '1970-01-01 00:00:00')
```